# How to allow crawlers access to index.php only, using robots.txt?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, robots.txt

If i want to only allow crawlers to access index.php, will this work?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.php
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to do this...wouldn't you want crawlers to index much more of your site?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it will work. Here's the test result from the [Google Webmaster Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-analysis-ac).

```
Url
http://www.example.org/index.php

Googlebot
Allowed by line 3: Allow: /index.php

Googlebot-Mobile
Allowed by line 3: Allow: /index.php
```

However, remember that with this configuration your site homepage won't be crawled unless the page is accessed with the full qualified path.
In other words, `http://www.example.org/` is forbidden while `http://www.example.org/index.php` is allowed.

If you want your homepage to be accessible, here's a better version of your file.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /$
```

Comment: Could you explain why the /$ works, or what it does?

Comment: Explanation for `/$` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29475539/1973409)

Answer (score 3):

Try swapping the order of Disallow / Allow:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.php
Disallow: /
```

See this info from wikipedia:

> "Yet, in order to be compatible to all
>   robots, if you want to allow single
>   files inside an otherwise disallowed
>   directory, you need to place the Allow
>   directive(s) first, followed by the
>   Disallow, for example:"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt

Still I wouldn't expect it to work too consistently

Answer (score 3):

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /index.php
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google Robots tool](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35237) to checkout. I would never put any secret directories in the robots file as I would guess that a line like below would be as honey for certain spiders.

```
Disallow: /secret
```

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /sitemap.xml
Allow: /robots.txt
Disallow: /

Sitemap: http://www.your-site-name.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?

Comment: `$` means "end of the line", so it matches `whateverdoma.in` - without any further URL characters