# What does the dollar sign mean in robots.txt

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

I am curious about a website and want to do some web crawling at the `/s` path. [Its robots.txt](http://mp.weixin.qq.com/robots.txt):

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /debug/
Allow: /qa/
Allow: /wiki/
Allow: /cgi-bin/loginpage
Disallow: /
```

My questions are:

- What does the dollar-sign mean in this case?
- And is it appropriate to crawl the URL `/s`? with respect to the robots.txt file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you follow the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), `$` has no special meaning, and there is no `Allow` field defined. A conforming bot would have to ignore fields it does not know, therefore such a bot would actually see this record:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

However, the original robots.txt specification has been extended by various parties. But as the authors of the robots.txt in question did not target a specific bot, we don’t know which "extension" they had in mind.

*Typically* (but not *necessarily*, as it’s not formally specified), `Allow` overwrites rules specified in `Disallow`, and `$` represents the end of the URL path.

Following this interpretation (it’s, for example, [used by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en)), `Allow: /$` would mean: You may crawl `/`, but you may not crawl `/a`, `/b` and so on.

So crawling of URLs whose path starts with `/s` would not be allowed (neither according to the original spec, thanks to `Disallow: /`, nor according to Google’s extension).