# Robots.txt disallow by regex

Tags: seo, robots.txt

On my website I have a page for the cart, that is: `http://www.example.com/cart` and another for the cartoons: `http://www.example.com/cartoons`. How should I write on my robots.txt file to ignore only the cart page?

The cart page does not accept an ending slash on the URL, so if I do:
`Disallow: /cart`, it will ignore `/cartoon` too.

I don't know if it's possible and it will be correctly parsed by the spider bots something like `/cart$`. I dont want to force `Allow: /cartoon` because may be another pages with the same prefix.

Answer (score 1):

In the [original `robots.txt` specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), this is not possible. It neither supports `Allow` nor any characters with special meaning inside a `Disallow` value.

But some consumers support additional things. For example, [Google gives a special meaning to the `$` sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475539/1591669), where it represents the end of the URL path:

```
Disallow: /cart$
```

For Google, this will block `/cart`, but not `/cartoon`.

Consumers that don’t give this special meaning [will interpret `$` literally](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67053/17633), so they will block `/cart$`, but not `/cart` or `/cartoon`.

So if using this, you should specify the bots in `User-agent`.

#### Alternative

Maybe you are fine with crawling but just want to prevent indexing? In that case you could use `meta`-`robots` (with a `noindex` value) instead of `robots.txt`. Supporting bots will still crawl the `/cart` page (and follow links, unless you also use `nofollow`), but they won’t index it.

```html
<!-- in the <head> of the /cart page -->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly allow and disallow both paths. More specific paths will take a higher precedent if they are longer in length:

```
disallow: /cart
allow: /cartoon
```

More info is available at: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: I may have more pages with the cart prefix